# unable to show name on each entry asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue when I select an employee name; the last name that was selected it is what is shown on the view but I would like the employee name to be change. Say for example I enter Trev and I click add, add another name Trudan; it should show all the names and not only Trudan. I suspect it is because of the for loop.

```
<table id=" myTable" >
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.CheckBox("TheOneCheckBoxToRuleThemAll")</th>

           <th class="col-lg-3">Requisition Number</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3 ">Employee</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3 ">Expense Account</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3 ">Description</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3 ">Item Number</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3 ">Quantity</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3 ">Requisition Date</th>

        </tr>


      @{

          if (@Model.items.Count > 0)
          {

              foreach (var item in Model.items)
              {

                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.postTrnx, new { @class = "checkGroup1" })</td>

                   <td class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.reqNumber) </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.employeeDetails.getName)</td>
                    <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.expense_account.getDescription</td>
                    <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.description</td>
                    <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.itemNumber</td>
                    <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.quantity</td>
                    <td class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.reqDate)</td>   
                </tr>

                  }
              }
          }

    </table>

   [ActionName("RequisitionItem")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [AcceptParameter(Name = "Add", Value = "Add")]
    public ActionResult AddItems(Requisition requisition, string expense_desc)
    {
        IssueDAO issuedb = new IssueDAO();
        ViewBag.StoresReps = issuedb.SelectEmployeesByDept("Stores");
        ViewBag.ReceivedByReps = issuedb.SelectEmployeesByDept(requisition.department);
        //getIssue.docNumber = issue.docNumber;
        //getIssue.docType = "Issue";
        getRequisition.department = requisition.department;
        getRequisition.employeeDetails.employeeNum = requisition.employeeDetails.employeeNum;
        //getRequisition.processedbyDetails.employeeNum = issue.processedbyDetails.employeeNum;
        //getIssue.expense_acccount = issue.expense_acccount;
        //getRequisition.expense_account = requisition.expense_account;
        getRequisition.reqDate = DateTime.Now;
        getRequisition.reqNumber = getRequisition.reqNumber;
        //Check to see if item is already exist on the current Issue
        for (int i = 0; i < getRequisition.items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (getRequisition.items[i].itemNumber == requisition.item.itemNumber)
            {
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "Item already exists";
                return View(getRequisition);
            }



        }
        //Check that the user only enters one item per request
        //if (getRequisition.items.Count >= 1)
        //{
        //    ViewBag.errorMessage = "Error, Only one item per request "; 
        //    return View(getRequisition);
        //}
        //Item validation Section
        if (items.Count == 0)
        {
            itemtbl.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            try
            {
                items = itemtbl.getItems();//Gets items from database
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogWrite logWriter = new LogWrite(ex.ToString());
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "Unable to Connect to Database. Please see Log file for more Information";
                return View(getRequisition);
            }

        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //Checks to see if item is in the database by searching for the item
            if (requisition.item.description == item.description)
            {
                //Checks to see if the item number specified matches that specified for the item
                if (requisition.item.itemNumber == item.itemNumber)
                {

                    requisition.item.lineNum = getRequisition.items.Count + 1;//Sets the line number to the index of the item plus one so has to have the Line number begin at 1
                    requisition.item.expense_account.account_desc = expense_desc;
                    string acc_desc = Regex.Replace(requisition.item.description, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9ęąół]", " ");
                    requisition.item.description = acc_desc;
                    getRequisition.addItems(requisition.item);
                    //getIssue.processedbyDetails.employeeNum = issue.processedbyDetails.employeeNum;
                    getRequisition.reqNumber = requisition.reqNumber;


                    //Reset the item varaible of the model to empty so as to accept new values
                    ModelState["item.itemNumber"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    ModelState["item.description"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    //ModelState["item.price"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    ModelState["item.quantity"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    return View(getRequisition);
                }
                ModelState["item.itemNumber"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                ModelState["item.description"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                //ModelState["item.price"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                ModelState["item.quantity"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "The Item Number and Description do not match";
                return View(getRequisition);
            }
        }
            ModelState["item.itemNumber"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            ModelState["item.description"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            //ModelState["item.price"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            ModelState["item.quantity"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            ViewBag.errorMessage = "Invalid Item Description";
            return View(getRequisition);

    }
```

Comment: Are you able to see (break point) if, in fact, all the expected items that you want are in your items list ?

Comment: Please, add the code from you controller's action (add button handler).

Comment: yes I get all the expected items

Comment: the employee name is pulling from another model; think it is because of the way it's done <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.employeeDetails.getName)</td>

Comment: You need to insert somehow model.employeeDetails into the list, then you can show the emplyeeName for any item.

Comment: insert it where

Comment: @MaximGoncharuk; could show me an example

Comment: I'm not sure what are getRequisition.items mean but you could try something like:
`getRequisition.items.Add(requisition.employeeDetails);`

Comment: If you are getting all your items, then you can step through your view code t see whether you are getting an error on rendering. Or you could just simplify your view code so that you are just displaying one simple property/label for each item.

Comment: I have changed it to this <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.employee_num.getName</td> but it is not outputting any names now

Comment: @DaniDev; can you show me an example

Comment: couple of simple things you can do: If the name is all you need add the name property to you item so that you can extract the name directly i.e. item.name  . Or maybe it is already accessible through item.employeeDetails.Name . You have to look at the model definitions

Comment: yeah i have something similiar but the employee name is not shown when i add that

Comment: how about the number (i.e. : @item.itemNumber) ?

Comment: We can't tell you the exact code you need because you have not provided the exact Model definitions or the access methods signature.

Comment: When I use this it is displayed <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.employeeDetails.getName)</td>; however when i use this   <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.employee_num.getName</td> no data is shown